# Apple bluetooth keyboard JKL showing 123

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

So somehow my wife has hit a series of keys on her Apple bluetooth keyboard where none of the keys work except for JKL, which now display 123. UIO displays 456 and 789 display normally. This indicates to me that it is stuck in some sort of numlock mode but for the life of me I can't find anything where someone indicates the correct way to "unstuck" it. It's one of those newer ones without a keypad and without a visible numlock key. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: An update. If I bring up the keyboard viewer and click the Capslock key while physically pressing the Fn key, it fixes itself. Once I log out it goes back to the way it was, however.

Comment: Just as an aside, I have tried fn+F6 without success.

Comment: OSX version 10.6.6

Comment: Have you tried taking the batteries out or unpairing the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I have. No dice.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem but I'm finding it really difficult.

Comment: Yes, my wife has no idea how she did it. This is leading to a lot of heaaches on my end :\ I appreciate you trying.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have the following problem: Mouse Keys are turned on. Turn them off under `System Preferences` > `Universal Access`.

---

The other option you could try is to remove the batteries from the keyboard, or disconnect and reconnect it. That might reset the thing.

Alternatively, have you rebooted the Mac at all since this happened?

Comment: I just checked and it's off. However the problem remains.

Comment: I have made a couple of new suggestions. I realise from reading your question that you've tried re-pairing the device, but the batteries might make a difference.

Comment: Yep, did the battery change thing too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done a reboot. I'll make sure to give that a try tonight just to make sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on an apple bluetooth keyboard I paired with my fedora desktop.
However, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> fixed this.